# Implementing a class that will override the onClick()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop, onclick

I want to create a method that, when implemented in other classes, you just need to pass some parameters and then call the - onclick() function to set the element.

At the moment, I´ve just done this. But this gives me a RunTimeException

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.testActivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

my code:

Class: clickeable

```
imports ...

public class ClickeableOptions implements View.OnClickListener{
    private CardView cardView;
    private Context cont;
    private Class actTarget;

    public OpcionesMainClickeables() {}

    public ClickeableOptions(CardView cardView, Context cont, Class actTarget) {
        this.cardView = cardView;
        this.cont = cont;
        this.actTarget= actTarget;
    }
        //Getters and Setters

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getCardView().setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getCont(), this.getActTarget());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And i want to implement this class like this...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private CardView cvRegistration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cvRegistration = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cvRegistration);

        ClickeableOptions optionRegistration = new ClickeableOptions(
                cvRegistration, this, Registration.class
        );

        optionRegistration.onClick(optionRegistration.getCardView());
    }
```

I've implemented the method in the same file, but I want to do it this way to keep things more tidy.
I think the problem is in the use of `this`, but i really don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to call `onClick` explicitly from your Activity. Just try like below:

```
public ClickeableOptions(CardView cardView, Context cont, Class actTarget) {
    this.cardView = cardView;
    this.cont = cont;
    this.actTarget= actTarget;

    this.cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

And inside `onClick`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getCont(), getActTarget());
    getCont().startActivity(intent);
}
```

And remove this line from Activity.

```
//optionRegistration.onClick(optionRegistration.getCardView());
```

Now when you clicked your CardView, Then Activity transitions start.

Comment: This is what I don't want to do, I've allready did this, works fine, but I want to keep it all separately, so, if i need to make another element clickeable, just need to create another object of `ClickeableOptions` and pass the args to it instead
Maybe is redundant, but for me is more organized

Comment: What do you want then, Please clarify

Comment: Sorry, didnt get your comment at first read.
i'll try this right now, Its in fact very new aproach for me.

Comment: That's it!!
Thanks a lot :D

Comment: If it works then why not accept the answer? The answer that you accept is same with my implementation and I provide you coding samples to understand better. Hope you understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

with

```
getCont().startActivity(intent);
```

Also, why are you inheriting ClickeableOptions from AppCompatActivity?

Comment: Works very well, no errors now, but it opens directly the target activity, rather than when the cardview is clicked.
The intheriting maybe is there from previous tests. I'll delete it

Answer (score 1):

1. Although you have instantiated the ClickeableOptions (derived from Activity) object, none of its Activity life cycle methods have been called and none of the super class instantiation related work (normally should be done in onCreate) has been accomplished. Hence the ActivityThread is simply null and you've got an exception when invoking
   `startActivity(intent);`
2. If you want to start another Activity  on your `CardView` click then you need to

   - follow Leo Leontev's advice:
     call 
     `getCont().startActivity(intent)`
     instead of 
     `startActivity(intent)`
   - move the line
     `getCardView().setOnClickListener(this)`
     to the `ClickeableOptions` custom constructor's most bottom line
   - delete this line from your `MainActivity$onCreate()` method:
     `optionRegistration.onClick(optionRegistration.getCardView());`

After all of above is done you'll be able to start new activity on click event.